# TreeSet. Как происходит сортировка?

Tags: java, коллекции

В TreeSet происходит сортировка от большего к меньшему?

Как определяется что больше а что меньше например со строками - "mp","jo".

И как работает метод `tailSet()`, я думал он выводит оставшиеся объекты, но это не так.

[image: NetBeans]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае сортировка строк происходит [лексикографически](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA), потому что по умолчанию используется компаратор для строк (а он как раз лексикографический)

Поэтому после добавления всех элементов ваш `TreeSet` будет выглядеть так:

```
1
123
13
Васька
Мурзик
Ры1жик
Рыжик
```

Метод `tailSet` вернет вам хвост вашего `TreeSet`, начиная с указанного элемента, а это как раз

```
Мурзик
Ры1жик
Рыжик
```

Как лексикографически определяется что больше?

"mp" и "jo" - сравниваются буквы m и j, буква j идет в алфавите раньше m, значит "jo" лексикографически меньше "mp".

"mp" и "4" - сравнение не строки и числа, а строки, состоящей и символов m и p и строки состоящей из символа 4. Опять же, сравниваем m и 4, 4 лексикографически меньше m (цифры в ascii идут раньше букв), соответственно строка "4" будет лексикографически меньше "mp".

**UPD**

Компаратор можно задать самостоятельно в таком конструкторе `TreeSet`:

```
TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator)
```

Например, если хотите чтобы строки сортировались по длине, сделайте так:

```
TreeSet<String> set = new TreeSet(new Comparator<String>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return Integer.compare(s1.length(), s2.length());
    }
});
```

и далее при добавлении строк в `TreeSet` они будут сортироваться по длине.

Comment: Т.е.  1 потом 1**2**3 потом 1**3** будет т.к. 2<3.

Comment: @антонсорокин, да, именно так

Comment: А можно изменить компаратор по умолчанию?

Comment: @антонсорокин, обновил ответ